# MS Exchange powershell command creates the wrong email id

Tags: asp.net, powershell

I am creating a ASP .NET application for MS Exchange administration. it will have some features like to create users mailbox.

I am using comamnd "enable-maibox -identity domainid -primarysmtpaddress emailId"

it wokrs well for the domain id which is as the format of "firstname.lastname"
it creates the email id as **firstname.lastname@company.com**

now problems come here when domain Id is in the format as "firstname.middlename.lastname"
it creates the email id as **firstname.lastname2@company.com** the expected email id is firstname.middlename.lastname@comapny.com

please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to change [Exchange email address policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232171%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) that defines naming schema for mailboxes, or you can disable policy adherence for individual mailbox.

To disable email address policy for mailbox you created

with Exchnage snap-in loaded say

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity <MailboxIdParameter> -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $false -PrimarySmtpAddress <SmtpAddress>
```

after you have enabled the mailbox for AD user.

I believe it should do the trick.